# Using Classes within an class

Tags: powershell

**Using other classes with a class in Powershell**

I have a question about working with classes in powershell, how does one use one class within another? For example I have the class 'SomeClass', I would like to declare that within the other class in the example class below.

**Pseudo Code:**

```
class SomeClass {
    [string] $Status
    [string] $Reason
}

class SomeMasterClass {
    [string] $ServerName
    [string] $FileName
    [SomeClass] $TheClass   # is this correct?
}
```

I am curious of this is the correct way to go about it or is there a better way?

Comment: But what exactly do you want to know? You're already using your `someClass` as a property of your `masterClass`. Could you provide more details?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon [SomeClass] $TheClass is wrong isn't it ? SomeMasterClass wont work I thought, I was trying to google this and I didn't see anything done the way I have it above.

Comment: I guess that is what I was trying to figure out, I am just trying to convert Add-Item .Net to pure Powershell code instead of using Add-Type. I also didn't see that I could do namespaces so I thought this was going to make the code above incorrect. ps. fixed the minor code issues in code.

Comment: `[SomeClass] $TheClass` is perfectly valid and will work

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon thanks, I guess I should close this, I can't give you the points either.. :-/

Comment: @MikeQ Preferably you'd update your post with _the actual question you'd like an answer to_. If you've realized you don't actually have a question after all, then delete your post :)

Comment: The question - and the corresponding solution - helped me. Only the search keyword "nesting" was missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you have a reduced simple example of how you can have a class as property of another class, you're actually already doing it just need to add a bit more to it.

- Definition

```
class SomeOtherClass {
    [string] $Status
    [string] $Reason

    SomeOtherClass () { }
    SomeOtherClass ([string] $Status, [string] $Reason) {
        $this.Status = $Status
        $this.Reason = $Reason
    }
}

class SomeClass {
    [string] $Server
    [string] $File
    [SomeOtherClass] $OtherClass

    SomeMasterClass () { }
    SomeMasterClass ([string] $Server, [string] $File, [SomeOtherClass] $Class) {
        $this.Server     = $Server
        $this.File       = $File
        $this.OtherClass = $Class
    }
}
```

- Instantiating

```
$testing = [SomeClass]@{
    Server = 'Server01'
    File   = 'SomeFile'
    OtherClass = [SomeOtherClass]@{
        Status = 'OK!'
        Reason = 'Idk'
    }
}
```

- Inspecting it's properties

```
PS ..\> $testing

Server   File     OtherClass
------   ----     ----------
Server01 SomeFile SomeOtherClass

PS ..\> $testing.OtherClass

Status Reason
------ ------
OK!    Idk
```